# RPAREN EQALOP and unbound variable and constructor errors in SML/ML

Tags: sml, ml

Said I have got 2 CNF logical phrases a,b and my distrib function should return the CNF form of a|b (a OR b).

Replacing rules that I've got are:

```
1) Replace p|(q&r) by (p|q)&(p|r) 
2) Replace (q&r)|p by (q|p)&(r|p)
```

A prop defined this way:

```
datatype prop = Atom of string | Not of prop | And of prop*prop | Or of prop*prop;
```

The function:

```
local
fun doOr(prop1,prop2) = (Or(prop1,prop2))

fun distrib1 (Or(Atom(sName1),Atom(sName2) ) ) = Or(Atom(sName1), Atom(sName2) )
    |distrib1 (Or(Not(Atom(sName1) ),Atom(sName2) ) ) = Or(Not(Atom(sName1) ), Atom(sName2) )
    | distrib1 (Or(Atom(sName1),Not(Atom(sName2) ) ) ) = Or(Atom(sName1), Not(Atom(sName2) ) )
    | distrib1 (Or(Not(Atom(sName1)),Not(Atom(sName2) ) ) ) = Or(Not(Atom(sName1)), Not(Atom(sName2) ) )
    | distrib1 (Or(prop1,And(prop2,prop3) ) ) = And( distrib1(Or(prop1,prop2) ), distrib1(Or(prop1,prop3) ) ) 
    | distrib1 (Or(And(prop1, prop2), prop3) ) ) = And( distrib1(Or(prop1,prop3) ), distrib1(Or(prop2,prop3) ) ) 

in
fun distrib (prop1,prop2) = distrib1(doOr(prop1,prop2) );
end;
```

Well, I don't know if the function itself is right although I just went through all the base options and the replacing rules but for now I get the above errors when the EQALOP appear after the distrib1 function and the constructors error appear the distrib function.

Why I get those errors? I am not sure but maybe I am supposed to use let and not local but then how can I transform it to a let structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last case of `distrib1` you have a total of 3 opening parentheses, but 4 closing:

```
| distrib1 (Or(And(prop1, prop2), prop3) ) ) =
```

Which is why you get the the syntax error about the RPAREN.

You're getting an error in `distrib` because `distrib1` has not been defined due to the syntax errors and thus it is an unknown variable. Fixing the syntax error in `distrib1` will fix this too.